# Modbus simulator weird behavior

Tags: io, serial-port, simulator, modbus

I am running the following modbus slave simulator http://www.modbusdriver.com/diagslave.html as well as the following modbus poller http://www.modbusdriver.com/modpoll.html. The weird thing is, I cna not however get them to discover each other. Here is the output from the slave simulator

```
Protocol configuration: Modbus RTU
Slave configuration: address = -1, master activity t/o = 3.00
Serial port configuration: /dev/ttyS0, 19200, 8, 1, even

Server started up successfully.
Listening to network (Ctrl-C to stop)
....................
```

and the following is the output from the modbus poller.

```
Protocol configuration: Modbus RTU
Slave configuration...: address = 1, start reference = 1, count = 1
Communication.........: /dev/ttyS0, 19200, 8, 1, even, t/o 1.00 s, poll rate 1000 ms
Data type.............: 16-bit register, output (holding) register table

-- Polling slave... (Ctrl-C to stop)
Reply time-out!
-- Polling slave... (Ctrl-C to stop)
```

As you can see, the modbus slave simulator as well as modbus poller both have the same values there should be able to find each other. However they can not which I find odd. Does anyone have any suggestions on what may be happening to cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time-out can be for various reasons such as

- register address your polling for does not exist in the slave device(also check if the type of register you are polling for is right)
- the connection has not been established between the slave & the master(this can be due to configuring the slave and the master serial port interfaces incorrectly).
- Also check if the serial link has been physically wired correctly to the correct pins on both ends (slave and master).

-Check the timeout period set at the master. You may have set it to a very low value and hence the responses from the slaves are being missed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I figured it out. There was not a built in API to interface with the device. So was sending data to the device and device was trying to send data back at the same time and not acting correctly. Wrote own driver now works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently had a case for Modbus
There are two examples in hand, you can refer to it

1. The way of socket

https://github.com/asgardpz/Modbus_Server

[https://github.com/asgardpz/Modbus_Client](https://github.com/asgardpz/Modbus_Server)

2. Use the hslcommunicationt component

[https://github.com/asgardpz/Hsl](https://github.com/asgardpz/Modbus_Server)

Readme.md has the screen of the program,
you can see if it is the sample you want